# Why the search text hide behind the header in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]

I am working search text from a div.Actually my search text is hidden behind the header.

Please take the following steps:

1. Click the fourth buttons of header. Search field is display enter "India"
2. Then press search button (10 times minimum). After few search by search text is behind the header.
3. I show it images. If you scroll up and down you can see the search match.

Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/q2HxP/2/

```
var searchIndex = -1;
var searchTermOld ='';

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.searchbox').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()===''){
      var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    searchTermOld = $(this).val();
  });
  $('.searchbox').on('keyup',function(){

    var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
    if($(this).val()===''){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
    }
    if($(this).val() !== searchTermOld){
     $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
      searchIndex = -1;
      $('.searchNext').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').attr("disabled", "disabled");                              
  }
  });
  $('.search').on('click',function(){


    if(searchIndex == -1){
      var searchTerm = $('.searchbox').val();
      if(searchTerm==''){
         PG_alert("Please Insert Text.")
        return ;
      }
      searchAndHighlight(searchTerm);
    }
    else searchNext();
    if($('.match').length >1){
      $('.searchNext').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.searchPrev').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });

  $('.searchNext').on('click',searchNext);

  $('.searchPrev').on('click',searchPrev);
});

function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var  selector= "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector+' span.match').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
                if (matches !==null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
           $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
         if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-15){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top)+500;
}
          return true;
        }else{
          PG_alert('Search not found.');
        }
      return false;
    }
  return false;
}

function searchNext(){
  searchIndex++;
  if (searchIndex >= $('.match').length) searchIndex = 0;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top)+500;
}
}

function searchPrev(){
  searchIndex--;
  if (searchIndex < 0) searchIndex = $('.match').length - 1;
  $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
  $('.match').eq(searchIndex).addClass('highlighted');
 if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $(window).height()-10){
  $(document).scrollTop($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top);
}
}

$(document).on('click', '.search_h', function() {
  //$( "#searchPopupScreen" ).popup( "open" )
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
  $(".searchbox").val('');
    $("#realTimeContents").css("height", "");

   $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
     // $('.searchbox').focus();
$("input[type=range]").val(60).slider("refresh");
   $(".searchContend_h").toggle("slow");
});

$(document).on('click', '.follow_h', function() {

 window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);


});
```

Any update of this question?

Comment: For one: your Fiddle is not working (errors) and second, what is your question?

Comment: here is working here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/q2HxP/2/

Comment: @putvande my question is that my search text is hide below the header .search for "india".click 4 button from header and search for "india"

Comment: You need to add some styling to your search container. Add position:fixed to keep it visible.

Comment: can you pleasse add on my fiddle ..actually first you look on my fiddle .Search for India then press search button again and again

Comment: any update? of this question?